# wkhtmltopdf does not respect page-break-after

Tags: macos, webkit, wkhtmltopdf

Using wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0_rc1 (weirdly reporting itself as 0.10.0 rc2) on MacOSX.

This input HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
      <style type="text/css">
        @page{
          size:   landscape;
          margin: 10mm;
        }
        div.page {
          height:             180mm;
          width:              274mm;
          overflow:           hidden;
          border:             1px solid #ddd;
          page-break-inside:  avoid;
          page-break-after:   always;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="page">Page 1</div>
      <div class="page">Page 2</div>
      <div class="page">Page 3</div>
    </body>
<html>
```

being processed like so:

```
wkhtmltopdf --orientation landscape input.html output.pdf
```

results in no page breaks:

[image: output pdf]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a problem of this specific version of wkhtmltopdf.

The most current version `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 (with patched qt)` does respect the page breaks.